# subset the string matches in the middle of the column from dataframe in R

Tags: r, string, dataframe

I need to subset the column that contains `uniprot/swiss-prot`: ID  from the data frame in R.The column contains other IDs also.
Below is an example:

```
biogrid:107054|entrez gene/locuslink:BAK1|uniprot/swiss-prot:Q16611|refseq:NP_001179
```

I need the below output:

```
Q16611
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use -

```
x <- 'biogrid:107054|entrez gene/locuslink:BAK1|uniprot/swiss-prot:Q16611|refseq:NP_001179'

sub('.*swiss-prot:(\\w+)\\|.*', '\\1', x)
#[1] "Q16611"
```

This will extract a word after `swiss-prot:` and `|` in the text.

For apply this to a dataframe column you can do -

```
df$result <- sub('.*swiss-prot:(\\w+)\\|.*', '\\1', df$col)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `str_extract`

```
library(stringr)
str_extract(x, "(?<=prot:)\\w+")
[1] "Q16611"
```

#### data

```
x <- 'biogrid:107054|entrez gene/locuslink:BAK1|uniprot/swiss-prot:Q16611|refseq:NP_001179'
```